# Snowflake get query_id for running query?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I want to get the query_id for the running query in Snowflake programatically. It seems like `account_usage.query_history` doesn't have running query ids stored. Is there are any other way to get the query_id of running query?

Comment: What do you mean by "programmatically"? If you're running the query with a driver such as the python driver then the query ID should be passed back to you automatically. Do you just mean with SQL?

Comment: @samud there have been a few answers below most in sql, were any of them what you were looking for? Be sure to mark a best answer. Clarifying which program you are planning to use would help with a more clarified answer. We are looking forward to hearing back from you.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you will need two sessions on your client application to get the query ID. You would only want to do this for long-running queries (for example to allow checking on status or aborting it after so many seconds), because you can get the query ID of a short query with last_query_id().

```
-- In first session, get the session ID before executing the long-running query.
select current_session() as SESSION_ID;

-- In second session, get the query ID of the running query in the first session
select  QUERY_ID
from    table(information_schema.query_history())
where   execution_status ='RUNNING' 
    and session_id = 172747880058954;
```

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#data-latency - Query_History has a data latency of up to 45 minutes, so you aren't guaranteed for the query to be in the Query_history table at the time you run the query.  At least, if I understand this documentation correctly?

Comment: The data latency it's discussing on that page is for the SNOWFLAKE database. This is a shared database from Snowflake to the customer and the latency can be up to 3 hours for some data. The second query in my sample will show recent activity. The INFORMATION_SCHEMA is instant while the SNOWFLAKE database ACCOUNT_USAGE schema has latency.

Comment: query_history() i function not snowflake db

Answer (score 0):

You can use information schema.

```
select *
from table(information_schema.query_history())  where execution_status ='RUNNING';
```

Comment: That would get any running query, not necessarily the one just run from a programmatic call.

Comment: add session_id = current_session() to query or and order by start_time desc limi1

Answer (score 0):

You can do either which return the ID for the most recently executed query

```
 select last_query_id();
```

Or `select last_query_id(1);`

which Return the ID for the first query executed in the session

Read more [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/last_query_id.html)

Comment: `last_query_id()` only shows the queries for this session, and thus if this session has a running query you cannot run another to ask what the current one is..

Answer (score 0):

There are other options provided but if you want to check for queries running for specific time (long running) you can use this query.

```
SET long_running_threshold_seconds = 10;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(information_schema.query_history()) WHERE (execution_status = 'RUNNING'
AND datediff('seconds',start_time,current_timestamp()) > $long_running_threshold_seconds )
```